# Domain manager to consolidate many domain here and there

Tags: domains

I have about 20 domains to manage. Some registered to the client (i impersonated him) and other register by me, under different name and address (over the years).

I like to get ALL THE DOMAINS under one roof, one easy to manage all the registration and order in one place..

what do you suggest...

- once in my life, i have try doteasy, which make domain managing super easy, but i don't like the prices...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a company which looks like it's going to be around for a few years and move all the domains to that company. Make sure that you have written agreements with the clients who you impersonated so that it's clear who owns the domain. If you used their contact details then when the domain transfer request comes through they are going to receive it and may wonder what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware that by impersonating the client on the domain registrations you are more than likely breaking the Terms and conditions of the Registry.

I know that Nominet state in section 4.1 of their Terms & Conditions that:

> give and keep us notified of your
>   correct name, postal address and any
>   phone, fax or e-mail information and
>   those of your contacts (if you appoint
>   any, see condition 5.2).  This duty
>   includes responding quickly and
>   correctly to any request from us to
>   confirm or correct the information on
>   the register;